# "if !DEBUG" - Debugging in controller not working in VSC

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

I already found a lot of threads about this topic but could not find a solution.

In my controller I have an if-statement to check if this is running in debug mode:

```
#if !DEBUG
[Authorize(Policy = "PolicyA")]
#endif
```

This part getts ignored and when using the controller I have to have the policy.

In my launch.json I have stated:

```
"ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
```

Running my application I get:

```
Hosting environment: Development
```

In my cshtml I have:

which is working.

I also added now this into my csproj:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

But the contoller if !debug keeps failing. I remember that this worked in VSC with .net 3 some years ago. Now I am using VSC with .net 8.

Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: AFAIK the environment your app runs in is entirely unrelated to the question of a debugger being attached or not. You can debug any environment you want.

Comment: @SanchoPanza is right. If environments determined DEBUG, there would be so much code that would be awkward and complicated to test before release. The asp.net-core environment and conditional symbols are orthogonal. Anyway, you should not toggle authorization in this manner. If you want different auth per env, configure a different policy based on the runtime value of the env.

Comment: `DEBUG` is a *compile-time* constant. Not a runtime one.